# Is it enough to show that two set of solutions of a problem have the same cardinality to show 1-to-1 correspondence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I have the following problem: prove that the integer solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with $(x, y, z) = 1$ are in 1-to-1 correspondence with the rational solutions to $u^2 + v^2 = 1$.

Now, I have obtained an integer parametrization of the Diophantine equation with $x=2rs, y = r^2 + s^2$ and $z = r^2 - s^2$. Moving things around in the Pythagorean theorem we find that we can take $u = \frac{2rs}{r^2 + s^2}$ and $v = \frac{r^2+s^2}{r^2 - s^2}$ to obtain $u^2 + v^2=1$ with rational solutions.

My question is this: am I done? Is it enough to show that we can go from one solution to the other? I feel like the answer is no and I should produce an isomorphism between both set of equations. But then I thought, being isomorphic is the same as having the same cardinality and since both set of solutions are countably infinite, by the definition of cardinality we would be done right?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just divide the equation through by $z^2$.

Comment: To show that two sets are in 1-to-1 correspondence, it is best to exhibit a 1-to-1 correspondence. $(a,b,c)\mapsto (\frac ab,\frac bc)$ and $(u,v)\mapsto \operatorname{leastcommondenominator}(u,v)\cdot(u,v,1)$ are readily seen to be inverses of each other and hence give us a 1-to-1 correspondence.

Comment: The problem is phrased in a way that may confuse   the beginner student; you aren’t just asked to show the two sets have the same cardinality (either both finite of the same size or both countably infinite in this case), but rather that there is a “natural way” to associate the solutions of one to the solutions of the other. Note that your parametrization does not establish a bijection as is, because you would need to verify that different triples $(x,y,z)$ yield different pairs of rationals, and that is not at all clear from what you did so far. (And that every $(u,v)$ is of this form.)

Comment: Thanks @HagenvonEitzen that's what I thought but I'm always looking for ways to "cheese" my way out of a difficult spot in my homework when I'm stuck.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin this is very helpful thank you.